# The supremum of a sequence of functions

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, supremum-and-infimum

Let $a \in \mathbb{R}_+$ and $n$ is a fixed positive integer

Let $f,g: [0,a] \to [0 , 2\pi]$ be two functions

I would like to know if is it true that
$$
\sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}
\sup_{r \in [0,a]}
\left|
\dfrac
{1}
{r \cdot n^{r \cdot i \cdot f(r)}}
-
\dfrac
{1}
{r \cdot n^{r \cdot i \cdot g(r)}}
\right|^2
<\infty
$$
Thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: $\sup_{r\in[0,r]}$ does not make sense.

Comment: this still doesnt make sense: If $r=0$ then you divide by $0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not true.

**Hint**:

Take $f=0,g=\pi$.
Define $r_n = \frac1{\log n}$.

Then the value after the second $\sup$ in your expression will go to $\infty$ for the sequence $(n,r_n)\in \mathbb N\times [0,2\pi]$.

Comment: thanks @supinf  for your correction and your answer